# VirtualBox VMs won't launch post re-install, kernel extensions unable to be loaded

Tags: big-sur, virtualbox

I am trying to launch my pre-existing VMs that were created before an OS upgrade to Big Sur. Currently using VirtualBox v6.1.20. Online research pointed to using the uninstall tool, restarting, installing the software again and then checking System Preferences security section to allow access. This option is not presenting itself.

Subsequent research talked about attempting to load the kernel extensions manually to see if that will invoke the prompt in System Preferences. This is my current result:

```
sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Unable to resolve dependencies for com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt: 'com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt, required by "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp, com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet1.kext, com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext, com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointIOP, com.hp.print.hpio.Deskjet.kext, com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverVSP, com.apple.nke.rvi, com.BlackBerry.driver.USBCDCNCM, com.hp.print.hpio.PhotosmartPro.kext, com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver, com.hp.print.hpio.inkjet8.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv, com.epson.print.kext.USBPrintClass, com.softraid.driver.SoftRAID, com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR, com.hp.hpio.hp_psa530_630_io_enabler, com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet4.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt, com.hp.kext.hp-fax-io, com.hp.print.hpio.Officejet.kext, com.hp.print.hpio.Designjet.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB, com.orderedbytes.driver.CMUSBPointer, com.intel.kext.intelhaxm, com.rim.driver.BlackBerryVirtualPrivateNetwork" names a dependency on 'com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass', which was not found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to resolve dependencies for com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt: 'com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt, required by "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp, com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet1.kext, com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext, com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointIOP, com.hp.print.hpio.Deskjet.kext, com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverVSP, com.apple.nke.rvi, com.BlackBerry.driver.USBCDCNCM, com.hp.print.hpio.PhotosmartPro.kext, com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver, com.hp.print.hpio.inkjet8.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv, com.epson.print.kext.USBPrintClass, com.softraid.driver.SoftRAID, com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR, com.hp.hpio.hp_psa530_630_io_enabler, com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet4.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt, com.hp.kext.hp-fax-io, com.hp.print.hpio.Officejet.kext, com.hp.print.hpio.Designjet.kext, org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB, com.orderedbytes.driver.CMUSBPointer, com.intel.kext.intelhaxm, com.rim.driver.BlackBerryVirtualPrivateNetwork" names a dependency on 'com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass', which was not found.}
```

I am seeing lots of references to BlackBerry packages but those should have been removed a while ago. It is also suggesting that the `com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass` might be missing.

Any thoughts on why the VMs and the VirtualBox extensions aren't able to load?

Comment: Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=VirtualBox++big+sur - there have been a lot of VB/macOS 11 issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the VirtualBox 6.1.22 update was able to correct the issue. During the installation process I received the notice to accept the kernel extension security permission that was not appearing previously.